# tkinter insert widget in a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make the following layout 
[tkinter layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEljx.png)
but the ID: label and the entry box are center left , and center right when then they should be next to each other , and they keep getting separated by the grid 
I am also trying to use a for loop to make the number pad but im not sure how to make a new variable outside of the loops, and increment by 1 in the loop that creates the button

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()


#BOTTOM FRAME SECTION

bottomframe = Frame(window,bg="cyan", width =900, height = 100)
bottomframe.pack(fill=BOTH,side=BOTTOM)
button = Button(window,text="LOG IN")
button.pack(fill=BOTH,side=BOTTOM)
checkbutton = Checkbutton(window, text="Use pseudonym?")
checkbutton.pack(side=BOTTOM)

topframe = Frame(window,bg="red",width =900, height = 100)
topframe.pack(fill=BOTH,side=TOP)
label1 = Label(window, text="Majestic 12 Identifier")
label1.pack(side=TOP)
label2 = Label(window, text="ID")
label2.pack(side=LEFT)
label3 = Label(window,text="Enter keycode:")
label3.pack(side=TOP)
entry1 = Entry(window)
entry1.pack(side=LEFT)

#GRID  SECTION
frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH,side=BOTTOM)

n = +1
for i in range(3):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame,i,weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame,i,weight=1)

for i in range(3):
    b = Button(frame, text="%d" % (i+n))
    for j in range(3):
        b = Button(frame, text="%d" % (j+1))
        b.grid(row=i, column=j,ipadx=2,ipady=2,padx=2,pady=2,sticky= W+E+N+S)

window.mainloop()
```

any help is welcome

Comment: Read up on [tkinter gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34277295/7414759)

Comment: @stovfl Thanks for the good link. I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I gave it a try. I played around a bit with the `Frame` objects. I deleted one, that was not needed. And I introduced `topframe2` in order to make it possible for `label2` and `entry1` to be in the same row.

Watch carefully the parent of the various entries and labels. Not everything should get the `window` object as direct parent.

I am using `expand` and `fill` arguments - here I am basically applying what I just learned at [Textbox not expanding with containing frame - TKinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893672/textbox-not-expanding-with-containing-frame-tkinter) and  [tkinter gui layout using frames and grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276663/tkinter-gui-layout-using-frames-and-grid/34277295#34277295)

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

# BOTTOM FRAME SECTION

topframe = Frame(window, width=900, height=100)
topframe.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP)

label1 = Label(topframe, text="Majestic 12 Identifier")
label1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

topframe2 = Frame(topframe, width=900, height=100)
topframe2.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP)

label2 = Label(topframe2, text="ID")
label2.pack(side=LEFT)

entry1 = Entry(topframe2)
entry1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)

label3 = Label(window, text="Enter keycode:")
label3.pack(side=TOP)

# GRID SECTION
frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack(fill=BOTH, side=TOP, expand=1)

n = +1
for i in range(3):
    Grid.rowconfigure(frame, i, weight=1)
    Grid.columnconfigure(frame, i, weight=1)

for i in range(3):
    b = Button(frame, text="%d" % (i + n))
    for j in range(3):
        b = Button(frame, text="%d" % (j + 1))
        b.grid(row=i, column=j, ipadx=2, ipady=2, padx=2, pady=2, sticky=W + E + N + S)

button = Button(window, text="LOG IN")
button.pack(fill=BOTH, side=BOTTOM)

checkbutton = Checkbutton(window, text="Use pseudonym?")
checkbutton.pack(side=BOTTOM)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop()
```